# Javascript: Find variable with highest and second highest value

Tags: javascript, loops

I want to make a loop to find highest and second highest player. I can not find instructions anywhere.

I have following variables:
`Player1 = 25`
`Player2 = 50`
`Player3 = 14`

I want to save the highest and second highest player in variable.
`var highest = highestplayer;`
`var secondhighest = secondhigest;`

Comment: Are your players stored inside an array?

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried several different code snippets that i have found but none of them seems to work for my purpose. I guess it would be doable with if clauses since the number of player is contant but the code would become quite long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the players in an array and sort the array:

```
players = [Player1, Player2, Player3];
players.sort(function(x, y) { return y - x; });

var highest = players[0];
var secondhighest = players[1];
```

If you want the player and the points, you should consider using objects:

```
Player1 = { name: 'Player1', points: 25 };
Player2 = { name: 'Player2', points: 50 };
Player3 = { name: 'Player3', points: 14 };

players = [Player1, Player2, Player3];
players.sort(function(x, y) { return y.points - x.points; });

var highest = players[0];
var secondhighest = players[1];

alert(highest.name + ': ' + highest.points);
alert(secondhighest.name + ': ' + secondhighest.points);
```

Comment: With this i am able to get the points but i do not know the player(or variable) in question.

Comment: If that's what you want, you have to store players and points differently. (In an object e.g.) You can't do what you want with `Player1 = 25` etc.

Comment: Any suggestions how would i be able to do that with objects? I have read about objects but have not been able to get it to work.

Comment: This one seems to work. I replaced the points with the variables i have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, players need to more than just a stored integer, so you can tell which is which. Then they need to be in an array.

```
var player1 = {name:"Player 1",score:"25"};
var player2 = {name:"Player 2",score:"50"};
var player3 = {name:"Player 3",score:"14"};
var players = [player1,player2,player3];
```

then you can quickly loop through and pull out the highest and second.

```
var highestplayer, secondhighest;
for (var i=players.length;i--;) { //quickly walks backwards through an array
  //if highest isn't set yet, or new player beats highest 
  if (!highestplayer || players[i].score > highestplayer.score) {
    //move highest down the ranks
    secondhighest = highestplayer;
    //set the new leader
    highestsplayer = players[i];

  }
  //if second not set or new player beats second
  else if (!secondhigest || player[i].score > secondhighest.score) {
    secondhighest = player[i];
  }
}
```

However, if you want to a full ranking, you'll need to use a sort function

```
players.sort(function(a,b) { return b.score-a.score });
```